# Material-ui: Module 'material-ui' has no exported members withStyles

Tags: reactjs, material-design, material-ui

Hi I am new to using material-ui. I am having issues when using material-ui-next.

I've done some research and removed the packages and reinstalled them. However, I keep getting the same error with 'withStyles'

Playing around with tables and/other components.

However I am getting this error: Module 'material-ui/styles' has no exported members 'withStyles'

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { withStyles } from 'material-ui/styles';
import AppBar from 'material-ui/AppBar';
import Toolbar from 'material-ui/Toolbar';
import Typography from 'material-ui/Typography';
import Button from 'material-ui/Button';
import IconButton from 'material-ui/IconButton';
import MenuIcon from 'material-ui-icons/Menu';

const styles = {
  root: {
    flexGrow: 1,
  },
  flex: {
    flex: 1,
  },
  menuButton: {
    marginLeft: -12,
    marginRight: 20,
  },
};

function ButtonAppBar(props) {
  const { classes } = props;
  return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
      <AppBar position="static">
        <Toolbar>
          <IconButton className={classes.menuButton} color="inherit" aria-label="Menu">
            <MenuIcon />
          </IconButton>
          <Typography variant="title" color="inherit" className={classes.flex}>
            Title
          </Typography>
          <Button color="inherit">Login</Button>
        </Toolbar>
      </AppBar>
    </div>
  );
}

ButtonAppBar.propTypes = {
  classes: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
};

export default withStyles(styles)(ButtonAppBar);
```

This is my package.json:

```
"dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.18.0",
    "material-ui": "^1.0.0-beta.39",
    "material-ui-icons": "^1.0.0-beta.36",
    "material-ui-next": "^1.0.0-beta.39",
    "material-ui-next-types": "^1.0.0",
    "prop-types": "^15.6.0",
    "react": "^16.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.2.0",
    "react-ionicons": "^2.1.6",
    "react-redux": "^5.0.7",
    "react-scripts": "1.1.1",
    "react-tap-event-plugin": "^3.0.2",
    "redux": "^3.7.2"
  },
```

I was previoulsy using material ui original version. Not material-ui-next. As I am trying to migrate I am also receiving this error. I was hoping to see if anyone could point me in the right direction and/or let me know what I am doing wrong.

> "Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components)
>   or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You
>   likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in,
>   or you might have mixed up default and named imports."

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your package.json dependencies should look like this:

```
"dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.18.0",
    "material-ui": "^1.0.0-beta.33",
    "material-ui-icons": "^1.0.0-beta.17",
    "prop-types": "^15.6.0",
    "react": "^16.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.2.0",
    "react-ionicons": "^2.1.6",
    "react-redux": "^5.0.7",
    "react-scripts": "1.1.1",
    "react-tap-event-plugin": "^3.0.2",
    "redux": "^3.7.2"
  }
```

I removed the material ui packages with `next` in their names.

Comment: Hi, @John Kennedy thanks for your help. I removed both dependencies that had the next. I am still seeing the issue with the import of { withStyles }. I think this might be also causing the second error I am receiving. I tried re-installing the packages for material-ui@next without any luck.

Comment: @AlejandroRoman Please install the exact versions I have specified in my package.json. This works on my machine, I am able to import `withStyles` with error.

Comment: fixed my issue. I am very grateful for your help! Thanks. Just out of curiosity, would you happen to know if it is because the latest version does not support those imports? It works, however my editor is still complaining about them.

Comment: I think the latest versions might have changed how `withStyles` is exported. A lot of things will change before the final version of the package is released. You simply have to stick to what is already working and keep it that way until the final version is released with final documentation.

Answer (score 0):

i was having issues but my path was wrong (using Beta.44) i just changed

```
import {StyleRules, withStyles, WithStyles} from 'material-ui/styles';
```

to

```
import {StyleRules, withStyles, WithStyles} from 'material-ui/styles/index';
```

this is a good resource 
https://medium.com/@liangchun/integrating-material-ui-next-with-your-react-typescript-project-80847f7eab64